# Hide column from View based on User Permission [Modern UI]

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, list-view, modern-experience

I have a SharePoint Modern list and there is a column in the default view that should be visible only to a group of people.

I have done it in Classic UI by using SPServices. Is there any way to achieve this fro Modern UI ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB way to hide column from list view based on user permission in SharePoint Online (Modern UI).

Comment: Ok that's fine. Is there any way to achieve this with SPFx webpart or extension ?

Answer (score 0):

I did sample test by hide list view Command previously so I think this can be done.

Check user permission.

https://www.eliostruyf.com/showing-or-hiding-sharepoint-framework-listview-custom-actions-based-on-permissions-and-selected-items/

[Inject custom CSS in SPFx application customizer](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)